# Where can I see the output of the viewer node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's assume that I want to see the frame value. I can't find it in the spreadsheet. Where can I find it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to plug geometry info into the [Viewer node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/output/viewer.html). Since you're trying to see a scalar and not a field you can pretty much use any non-empty geometry.

It will be evaluated like if it was a field on the domain you have selected.

[image]

If you use a heavily subdivided mesh all the viewer column values will be set to the value you want to view. It might adversely affect performance though.

[image]

Comment: I like the way you can debug in AN, just plug any value to it and see it in the node. I hope that gets implemented in GN

Comment: Yes it is a bit awkward, I'm sure this will be improved in a future iteration of Geometry Nodes